# Update global nested list variable in function irrespective of depth

Tags: r

I am attempting to create a function that can update selected values in a global environment variable. To complicate things, these values are located in nested lists, and the depth of the location can vary.

Here is one example:

```
L <- list()

L$Foo <- list()
L$Foo$Bar <- list()
L$Foo$Bar$VAR <- TRUE

L$Lorem <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor <- list()
L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR <- TRUE
```

I am trying to update `L$Foo$Bar$VAR <- TRUE` to `L$Foo$Bar$VAR <- FALSE` and `L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR <- TRUE` to `L$Lorem$Ipsum$Dolor$VAR <- FALSE`. As you see, the variable name inside the nested list, `VAR`, is the same across all variables I want to update.

Hence, I'm seeking out a function that can update all `VAR` variables inside a nested list, regardless of how deep `VAR` is.

**EDIT** `VAR` will be updated with the same value.

Comment: @RonakShah I updated the question now. `VAR` will be updated with the same value on my case, being set either to `TRUE` or to `FALSE`. I can identify the number of `VAR` in `L` if necessary, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) rrapply** `rrapply` in package rrapply will walk `L` and for each element satisfying the condition defined by the second argument it will run the third argument replacing the value with that argument's output.

```
library(rrapply)

L2 <- rrapply(L, function(x, .xname) .xname == "VAR", function(x) FALSE)
str(L2)
```

giving:

```
List of 2
 $ Foo  :List of 1
  ..$ Bar:List of 1
  .. ..$ VAR: logi FALSE
 $ Lorem:List of 1
  ..$ Ipsum:List of 1
  .. ..$ Dolor:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ VAR: logi FALSE
```

**2) rapply** If it were known that the `VAR` components are the only logical components (which in the question's example is the case) then `rapply` in the base of R could be used.

```
rapply(L, function(x) FALSE, classes = "logical", how = "replace")
```

**3) base R**  Using only base R we can recursively walk the tree looking for the indicated name and replacing its value with FALSE.

```
replace_name <- function(x, name, value) {
  if (is.list(x)) {
    Map(function(nm) 
      if (nm == name) value else replace_name(x[[nm]], name, value), names(x)
    )
  } else x
}

replace_name(L, "VAR", FALSE)
```

### Global Environment

If we have computed L2 by one of the above means within a function and want to replace L in the global environment with it as a side effect of the function then we can use any of these:

```
.GlobalEnv$L <- L2

 L <<- L2

 assign("L", L2, .GlobalEnv)
```

Normally R functions don't operate through side effects so if you can arrange just to return it that would be even better.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for a thorough answer with multiple alternative solutions!